# Using Razor View Engine within JavaScript

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Using the new ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Razor View Engine, is there any way to call upon it within javascript code?

In the normal view engine, you could do something like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      function somejQueryFunction(obj) {
         <%= obj.ExecuteSomething() %>
      }
    });
</script>
```

But I cannot find any way to do similar with Razor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function somejQueryFunction(obj) {
        @obj.ExecuteSomething()
    }
});
</script>
```

Basically any time you have `<%: Expression %>` or `<%= Expression %>` you can replace it with `@Expression`